# Example url to check DTLS connetion

Tags: dtls, mbedtls

Can anyone please suggest an url to check the DTLS connection.
For eg. https://www.howsmyssl.com/ is used to test the TLS protocol.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Mbed TLS provides a DTLS [server](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/programs/ssl/dtls_server.c) and [client](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/programs/ssl/dtls_client.c) sample applications, which you can use to test your DTLS solution against. If you are already using Mbed TLS as your solution, and you wish to test interoperability, you can use a third party DTLS application, such as `OpenSSL s_server -dtls` \ `OpenSSL s_client -dtls` or `gnutls-serv -u` \ `gnutls-cli -u`.

Comment: Would have been great to see some example output from that client. Also, provide links to 3rd party apps, you used. What's the difference between `s_client` and `s_server`?